# TFRecords 100x larger than original size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm converting train images in the local folder to TFRecords using dataset_tool.py from StyleGAN github repo. This is the code:

```
 def create_from_images(tfrecord_dir, image_dir, shuffle):
    print('Loading images from "%s"' % image_dir)
    image_filenames = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(image_dir, '*')))
    if len(image_filenames) == 0:
        error('No input images found')

    img = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open(image_filenames[0]))
    resolution = img.shape[0]
    channels = img.shape[2] if img.ndim == 3 else 1
    if img.shape[1] != resolution:
        error('Input images must have the same width and height')
    if resolution != 2 ** int(np.floor(np.log2(resolution))):
        error('Input image resolution must be a power-of-two')
    if channels not in [1, 3]:
        error('Input images must be stored as RGB or grayscale')

    with TFRecordExporter(tfrecord_dir, len(image_filenames)) as tfr:
        order = tfr.choose_shuffled_order() if shuffle else np.arange(len(image_filenames))
        for idx in range(order.size):
            img = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open(image_filenames[order[idx]]))
            if channels == 1:
                img = img[np.newaxis, :, :] # HW => CHW
            else:
                img = img.transpose([2, 0, 1]) # HWC => CHW
            tfr.add_image(img)

 def add_image(self, img):
     if self.print_progress and self.cur_images % self.progress_interval == 0:
            print('%d / %d\r' % (self.cur_images, self.expected_images), end='', flush=True)
     if self.shape is None:
            self.shape = img.shape
            self.resolution_log2 = int(np.log2(self.shape[1]))
            assert self.shape[0] in [1, 3]
            assert self.shape[1] == self.shape[2]
            assert self.shape[1] == 2**self.resolution_log2
            tfr_opt = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.NONE)
            for lod in range(self.resolution_log2 - 1):
                tfr_file = self.tfr_prefix + '-r%02d.tfrecords' % (self.resolution_log2 - lod)
                self.tfr_writers.append(tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfr_file, tfr_opt))
        assert img.shape == self.shape
        for lod, tfr_writer in enumerate(self.tfr_writers):
            if lod:
                img = img.astype(np.float32)
                img = (img[:, 0::2, 0::2] + img[:, 0::2, 1::2] + img[:, 1::2, 0::2] + img[:, 1::2, 1::2]) * 0.25
            quant = np.rint(img).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
            ex = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'shape': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=quant.shape)),
                'data': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[quant.tostring()]))}))
            tfr_writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
        self.cur_images += 1
```

It creates TFRecords files with several resolutions up to original. So created TFRecords with the original resoultion is 100x larger than original folder with files. My original files are BW png 2  kilobytes each with the folder size 120 MB. While TFRecords I receive is 12 GB. I know that TFRecords are usually larger than original but not 100x! What may be the problem here?

Comment: How does the size of the records compare to the size of the uncompressed image data?

Comment: The problem is that the original images are in a compressed format (JPEG I imagine, or maybe PNG) and the data that you are saving in the records files is uncompressed. If you want to keep the same size, save the bytes of the image files as a `tf.string` in the records and the when you parse the record you decode it with [`tf.io.decode_image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image) for example (which will obviously have some overhead on the TensorFlow part, that's the tradeoff).

Comment: @jdehesa I thought this line is doing it `'data': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[quant.tostring()]))}))`

Comment: @IvanSmirnov That line serializes all the array into a long `tf.string`, yes, but it is still an uncompressed bitmap. For each pixel in each image you will have one or three bytes (depending on the number of channels). It's like saving all images in BMP format. When the image is compressed in PNG it takes far less space, because PNG uses a (lossless) compression algorithm (which is why you cannot use PNG data directly, you have to decode it first, either with PIL, like you do here, or later with TensorFlow).

Comment: @jdehesa Clear, thanks. So how do I convert it to tf.string with the same bytes? And also as I understand it anyway needs decoding like this one `tf.decode_raw(features['data'], tf.uint8)`. Will in this case it need other decoding with extra resources needed?

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Actually [`tf.io.decode_image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image) work directly on a scalar `tf.string` (see docs), so in principle you don't need [`tf.io.decode_raw`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_raw). If you have an image that you want to convert to record, you can get its bytes with something like `with open(img_path, 'rb') as f: img_file_bytes = f.read()`.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov If you need to manipulate the image, though, you would have to recompress it with [`save`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save), writing it to a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#buffered-streams) and then retrieving the bytes with `getvalue()` for example.

Comment: @jdehesa, I'm a little confused. In this code the image is a numpy array saved to a string. What should be changed in order to save the compressed image?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are saving the images uncompressed in the record files, which takes far more space than the compressed image files. To avoid this, you could directly write the image files as records but, since you are doing some image processing first, you would have to do that processing and the save the resulting image again in a compressed format. You can convert an image array into its PNG compressed form with a function like this:

```
import io
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def img2png(image):
    # Assumes image was passed in CHW format
    img = Image.fromarray(np.moveaxis(image, 0, 2))
    with io.BytesIO() as img_bytes:
        img.save(img_bytes, 'PNG')
        return img_bytes.getvalue()
```

In your example, you could then save your `quant` images like this.

```
ex = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'shape': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=quant.shape)),
    'data': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[img2png(quant)]))}))
```

Note that, since you are saving compressed images, you will need to use [`tf.io.decode_image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image) when parsing the records later. This is the overhead you have to "pay" for the reduced size on disk.

Answer (score 0):

The solution recommended by [@jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59030450/995380), is already implemented in the following StyleGAN fork: https://github.com/skyflynil/stylegan2

Images in tfrecords are stored as original jpegs and tfrecords are much more smaller.